# I am trying to install vc2017redist_x64 in order to have obs installed on my windows 7 computer

Tags: windows-7

Unfortunately the setup keeps failing about halfway through and just gives me 0x80240017 - unspecified error.

This is the log file that it also spits out.

```
[0EB4:0EF0][2019-07-17T10:03:59]i001: Burn v3.7.3813.0, Windows v6.1 (Build 7601: Service Pack 1), path: C:\Users\Samuroy7\Desktop\vc2017redist_x64.exe, cmdline: ''
[0EB4:0EF0][2019-07-17T10:03:59]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleLog' to value 'C:\Users\Samuroy7\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_vcredist_amd64_20190717100359.log'
[0EB4:0EF0][2019-07-17T10:03:59]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleOriginalSource' to value 'C:\Users\Samuroy7\Desktop\vc2017redist_x64.exe'
[0EB4:0EF0][2019-07-17T10:03:59]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleOriginalSourceFolder' to value 'C:\Users\Samuroy7\Desktop\'
[0EB4:0EF0][2019-07-17T10:03:59]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleName' to value 'Microsoft Visual C++ 2017 Redistributable (x64) - 14.15.26706'
[0EB4:0EF0][2019-07-17T10:04:00]i100: Detect begin, 10 packages
[0EB4:0EF0][2019-07-17T10:04:00]i000: File search: windows_uCRT_DetectKey, did not find path: C:\Windows\system32\ucrtbase.dll
[0EB4:0EF0][2019-07-17T10:04:00]i000: File search: windows_uCRT_DetectKeyExists, did not find path: C:\Windows\system32\ucrtbase.dll
[0EB4:0EF0][2019-07-17T10:04:00]i000: Setting numeric variable 'windows_uCRT_DetectKeyExists' to value 0
[0EB4:0EF0][2019-07-17T10:04:00]i052: Condition '(VersionNT = v6.3 AND NOT VersionNT64) AND (windows_uCRT_DetectKeyExists AND windows_uCRT_DetectKey >= v10.0.10240.0)' evaluates to false.
[0EB4:0EF0][2019-07-17T10:04:00]i052: Condition '(VersionNT = v6.3 AND VersionNT64) AND (windows_uCRT_DetectKeyExists AND windows_uCRT_DetectKey >= v10.0.10240.0)' evaluates to false.
[0EB4:0EF0][2019-07-17T10:04:00]i052: Condition '(VersionNT = v6.2 AND NOT VersionNT64) AND (windows_uCRT_DetectKeyExists AND windows_uCRT_DetectKey >= v10.0.10240.0)' evaluates to false.
[0EB4:0EF0][2019-07-17T10:04:00]i052: Condition '(VersionNT = v6.2 AND VersionNT64) AND (windows_uCRT_DetectKeyExists AND windows_uCRT_DetectKey >= v10.0.10240.0)' evaluates to false.
[0EB4:0EF0][2019-07-17T10:04:00]i052: Condition '(VersionNT = v6.1 AND NOT VersionNT64) AND (windows_uCRT_DetectKeyExists AND windows_uCRT_DetectKey >= v10.0.10240.0)' evaluates to false.
[0EB4:0EF0][2019-07-17T10:04:00]i052: Condition '(VersionNT = v6.1 AND VersionNT64) AND (windows_uCRT_DetectKeyExists AND windows_uCRT_DetectKey >= v10.0.10240.0)' evaluates to false.
[0EB4:0EF0][2019-07-17T10:04:00]i052: Condition '(VersionNT = v6.0 AND NOT VersionNT64) AND (windows_uCRT_DetectKeyExists AND windows_uCRT_DetectKey >= v10.0.10240.0)' evaluates to false.
[0EB4:0EF0][2019-07-17T10:04:00]i052: Condition '(VersionNT = v6.0 AND VersionNT64) AND (windows_uCRT_DetectKeyExists AND windows_uCRT_DetectKey >= v10.0.10240.0)' evaluates to false.
[0EB4:0EF0][2019-07-17T10:04:00]i101: Detected package: Windows81_x86, state: Absent, cached: None
[0EB4:0EF0][2019-07-17T10:04:00]i101: Detected package: Windows81_x64, state: Absent, cached: None
[0EB4:0EF0][2019-07-17T10:04:00]i101: Detected package: Windows8_x86, state: Absent, cached: None
[0EB4:0EF0][2019-07-17T10:04:00]i101: Detected package: Windows8_x64, state: Absent, cached: None
[0EB4:0EF0][2019-07-17T10:04:00]i101: Detected package: Windows7_MSU_x86, state: Absent, cached: None
[0EB4:0EF0][2019-07-17T10:04:00]i101: Detected package: Windows7_MSU_x64, state: Absent, cached: None
[0EB4:0EF0][2019-07-17T10:04:00]i101: Detected package: WindowsVista_MSU_x86, state: Absent, cached: None
[0EB4:0EF0][2019-07-17T10:04:00]i101: Detected package: WindowsVista_MSU_x64, state: Absent, cached: None
[0EB4:0EF0][2019-07-17T10:04:00]i101: Detected package: vcRuntimeMinimum_x64, state: Absent, cached: Complete
[0EB4:0EF0][2019-07-17T10:04:00]i101: Detected package: vcRuntimeAdditional_x64, state: Absent, cached: Complete
[0EB4:0EF0][2019-07-17T10:04:00]i052: Condition 'VersionNT64 >= v6.0 OR (VersionNT64 = v5.2 AND ServicePackLevel >= 1)' evaluates to true.
[0EB4:0EF0][2019-07-17T10:04:00]i199: Detect complete, result: 0x0
[0EB4:0EF0][2019-07-17T10:04:01]i200: Plan begin, 10 packages, action: Install
[0EB4:0EF0][2019-07-17T10:04:01]i052: Condition 'VersionNT = v6.3 AND NOT VersionNT64' evaluates to false.
[0EB4:0EF0][2019-07-17T10:04:01]w321: Skipping dependency registration on package with no dependency providers: Windows81_x86
[0EB4:0EF0][2019-07-17T10:04:01]i052: Condition 'VersionNT = v6.3 AND VersionNT64' evaluates to false.
[0EB4:0EF0][2019-07-17T10:04:01]w321: Skipping dependency registration on package with no dependency providers: Windows81_x64
[0EB4:0EF0][2019-07-17T10:04:01]i052: Condition 'VersionNT = v6.2 AND NOT VersionNT64' evaluates to false.
[0EB4:0EF0][2019-07-17T10:04:01]w321: Skipping dependency registration on package with no dependency providers: Windows8_x86
[0EB4:0EF0][2019-07-17T10:04:01]i052: Condition 'VersionNT = v6.2 AND VersionNT64' evaluates to false.
[0EB4:0EF0][2019-07-17T10:04:01]w321: Skipping dependency registration on package with no dependency providers: Windows8_x64
[0EB4:0EF0][2019-07-17T10:04:01]i052: Condition 'VersionNT = v6.1 AND NOT VersionNT64' evaluates to false.
[0EB4:0EF0][2019-07-17T10:04:01]w321: Skipping dependency registration on package with no dependency providers: Windows7_MSU_x86
[0EB4:0EF0][2019-07-17T10:04:01]i052: Condition 'VersionNT = v6.1 AND VersionNT64' evaluates to true.
[0EB4:0EF0][2019-07-17T10:04:01]w321: Skipping dependency registration on package with no dependency providers: Windows7_MSU_x64
[0EB4:0EF0][2019-07-17T10:04:01]i052: Condition 'VersionNT = v6.0 AND NOT VersionNT64' evaluates to false.
[0EB4:0EF0][2019-07-17T10:04:01]w321: Skipping dependency registration on package with no dependency providers: WindowsVista_MSU_x86
[0EB4:0EF0][2019-07-17T10:04:01]i052: Condition 'VersionNT = v6.0 AND VersionNT64' evaluates to false.
[0EB4:0EF0][2019-07-17T10:04:01]w321: Skipping dependency registration on package with no dependency providers: WindowsVista_MSU_x64
[0EB4:0EF0][2019-07-17T10:04:01]i052: Condition '(VersionNT64)' evaluates to true.
[0EB4:0EF0][2019-07-17T10:04:01]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleRollbackLog_vcRuntimeMinimum_x64' to value 'C:\Users\Samuroy7\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_vcredist_amd64_20190717100359_001_vcRuntimeMinimum_x64_rollback.log'
[0EB4:0EF0][2019-07-17T10:04:01]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleLog_vcRuntimeMinimum_x64' to value 'C:\Users\Samuroy7\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_vcredist_amd64_20190717100359_001_vcRuntimeMinimum_x64.log'
[0EB4:0EF0][2019-07-17T10:04:01]i052: Condition '(VersionNT64)' evaluates to true.
[0EB4:0EF0][2019-07-17T10:04:01]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleRollbackLog_vcRuntimeAdditional_x64' to value 'C:\Users\Samuroy7\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_vcredist_amd64_20190717100359_002_vcRuntimeAdditional_x64_rollback.log'
[0EB4:0EF0][2019-07-17T10:04:01]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleLog_vcRuntimeAdditional_x64' to value 'C:\Users\Samuroy7\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_vcredist_amd64_20190717100359_002_vcRuntimeAdditional_x64.log'
[0EB4:0EF0][2019-07-17T10:04:01]i201: Planned package: Windows81_x86, state: Absent, default requested: Absent, ba requested: Absent, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: None
[0EB4:0EF0][2019-07-17T10:04:01]i201: Planned package: Windows81_x64, state: Absent, default requested: Absent, ba requested: Absent, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: None
[0EB4:0EF0][2019-07-17T10:04:01]i201: Planned package: Windows8_x86, state: Absent, default requested: Absent, ba requested: Absent, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: None
[0EB4:0EF0][2019-07-17T10:04:01]i201: Planned package: Windows8_x64, state: Absent, default requested: Absent, ba requested: Absent, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: None
[0EB4:0EF0][2019-07-17T10:04:01]i201: Planned package: Windows7_MSU_x86, state: Absent, default requested: Absent, ba requested: Absent, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: None
[0EB4:0EF0][2019-07-17T10:04:01]i201: Planned package: Windows7_MSU_x64, state: Absent, default requested: Present, ba requested: Present, execute: Install, rollback: Uninstall, cache: Yes, uncache: No, dependency: None
[0EB4:0EF0][2019-07-17T10:04:01]i201: Planned package: WindowsVista_MSU_x86, state: Absent, default requested: Absent, ba requested: Absent, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: None
[0EB4:0EF0][2019-07-17T10:04:01]i201: Planned package: WindowsVista_MSU_x64, state: Absent, default requested: Absent, ba requested: Absent, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: None
[0EB4:0EF0][2019-07-17T10:04:01]i201: Planned package: vcRuntimeMinimum_x64, state: Absent, default requested: Present, ba requested: Present, execute: Install, rollback: Uninstall, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: Register
[0EB4:0EF0][2019-07-17T10:04:01]i201: Planned package: vcRuntimeAdditional_x64, state: Absent, default requested: Present, ba requested: Present, execute: Install, rollback: Uninstall, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: Register
[0EB4:0EF0][2019-07-17T10:04:01]i299: Plan complete, result: 0x0
[0EB4:0EF0][2019-07-17T10:04:01]i300: Apply begin
[09E4:0DBC][2019-07-17T10:04:03]i360: Creating a system restore point.
[09E4:0DBC][2019-07-17T10:04:07]i361: Created a system restore point.
[09E4:0DBC][2019-07-17T10:04:07]i370: Session begin, registration key: SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{95ac1cfa-f4fb-4d1b-8912-7f9d5fbb140d}, options: 0x7, disable resume: No
[09E4:0DBC][2019-07-17T10:04:07]i000: Caching bundle from: 'C:\Users\Samuroy7\AppData\Local\Temp\{95ac1cfa-f4fb-4d1b-8912-7f9d5fbb140d}\.be\VC_redist.x64.exe' to: 'C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{95ac1cfa-f4fb-4d1b-8912-7f9d5fbb140d}\VC_redist.x64.exe'
[09E4:0DBC][2019-07-17T10:04:07]i320: Registering bundle dependency provider: ,,amd64,14.0,bundle, version: 14.15.26706.0
[09E4:0DBC][2019-07-17T10:04:07]i371: Updating session, registration key: SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{95ac1cfa-f4fb-4d1b-8912-7f9d5fbb140d}, resume: Active, restart initiated: No, disable resume: No
[09E4:0AD0][2019-07-17T10:04:07]i304: Verified existing payload: Windows7_MSU_x64 at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\.unverified\Windows7_MSU_x64.
[09E4:0AD0][2019-07-17T10:04:07]i305: Verified acquired payload: Windows7_MSU_x64 at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\.unverified\Windows7_MSU_x64, moving to: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\54050A5F8AE7F0C56E553F0090146C17A1D2BF8D\packages\Patch\x64\Windows6.1-KB2999226-x64.msu.
[09E4:0AD0][2019-07-17T10:04:07]i304: Verified existing payload: vcRuntimeMinimum_x64 at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{C77195A4-CEB8-38EE-BDD6-C46CB459EF6E}v14.15.26706\packages\vcRuntimeMinimum_amd64\vc_runtimeMinimum_x64.msi.
[09E4:0AD0][2019-07-17T10:04:07]i304: Verified existing payload: cab5046A8AB272BF37297BB7928664C9503 at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{C77195A4-CEB8-38EE-BDD6-C46CB459EF6E}v14.15.26706\packages\vcRuntimeMinimum_amd64\cab1.cab.
[09E4:0AD0][2019-07-17T10:04:07]i304: Verified existing payload: vcRuntimeAdditional_x64 at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{F106B700-BFF8-3065-B305-14D36AD40539}v14.15.26706\packages\vcRuntimeAdditional_amd64\vc_runtimeAdditional_x64.msi.
[09E4:0AD0][2019-07-17T10:04:07]i304: Verified existing payload: cab2C04DDC374BD96EB5C8EB8208F2C7C92 at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{F106B700-BFF8-3065-B305-14D36AD40539}v14.15.26706\packages\vcRuntimeAdditional_amd64\cab1.cab.
[09E4:0DBC][2019-07-17T10:04:07]i301: Applying execute package: Windows7_MSU_x64, action: Install, path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\54050A5F8AE7F0C56E553F0090146C17A1D2BF8D\packages\Patch\x64\Windows6.1-KB2999226-x64.msu, arguments: '"C:\Windows\SysNative\wusa.exe" "C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\54050A5F8AE7F0C56E553F0090146C17A1D2BF8D\packages\Patch\x64\Windows6.1-KB2999226-x64.msu" /quiet /norestart'
[09E4:0DBC][2019-07-17T10:04:29]e000: Error 0x80240017: Failed to execute MSU package.
[0EB4:0EF0][2019-07-17T10:04:29]e000: Error 0x80240017: Failed to configure per-machine MSU package.
[0EB4:0EF0][2019-07-17T10:04:29]i319: Applied execute package: Windows7_MSU_x64, result: 0x80240017, restart: None
[0EB4:0EF0][2019-07-17T10:04:29]e000: Error 0x80240017: Failed to execute MSU package.
[09E4:0DBC][2019-07-17T10:04:29]i372: Session end, registration key: SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{95ac1cfa-f4fb-4d1b-8912-7f9d5fbb140d}, resume: None, restart: None, disable resume: No
[09E4:0DBC][2019-07-17T10:04:29]i330: Removed bundle dependency provider: ,,amd64,14.0,bundle
[09E4:0DBC][2019-07-17T10:04:29]i352: Removing cached bundle: {95ac1cfa-f4fb-4d1b-8912-7f9d5fbb140d}, from path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{95ac1cfa-f4fb-4d1b-8912-7f9d5fbb140d}\
[09E4:0DBC][2019-07-17T10:04:29]i371: Updating session, registration key: SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{95ac1cfa-f4fb-4d1b-8912-7f9d5fbb140d}, resume: None, restart initiated: No, disable resume: No
[0EB4:0EF0][2019-07-17T10:04:29]i399: Apply complete, result: 0x80240017, restart: None, ba requested restart:  No
```

could anyone help me out with this?
also I already have service pack 1 on this windows.
other details:
I have preformed a clean boot.
I have already uninstalled the other c++ so that they would not interfere with this one.

Answer (score 0):

From Microsoft Answers - [windows update error: 0x80240017](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-update/windows-update-error-0x80240017/3d475e8c-4cdc-491a-aba4-eb4b072b0d8e)

> Step 1:
>
> 1. Press Windows + X and select Control panel.
> 2. In the search box, type troubleshooter, and then click Troubleshooting.
> 3. Under System and Security, click Fix problems with Windows Updates.
>
> Step 2:
>
> If the issue persists, I suggest you to reset the Windows update components manually and check if it helps.
>
> 1. Press Windows key + X on the desktop screen of the computer.
> 2. Select Command Prompt (Admin).
> 3. On the open Command Prompt window copy and paste the commands (all at once).    >
>
>    ```
>    net stop wuauserv
>
>    net stop cryptSvc
>
>    net stop bits
>
>    net stop msiserver
>
>    ren C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution SoftwareDistribution.old
>
>    ren C:\Windows\System32\catroot2 catroot2.old
>
>    net start wuauserv
>
>    net start cryptSvc
>
>    net start bits
>
>    net start msiserver
>
>    pause
>    ```
> 4. Exit the command prompt and check if it helps.